# python cant call a global variable

Tags: python, variables, nameerror

Edit: problem solved why are you still giving negative points

i created a function like this:

```
def testFunc():
    global testVar

    if True:
        testVar = input("input something: ")

def anotherFunc():
    if testVar == "test":
        print("okay")

anotherFunc() #calling function
```

but im getting an error:

> File "C:/Users/jeffpc/Desktop/Files/wqw.py", line 8, in anotherFunc
> if testVar == "test":
> NameError: name 'testVar' is not defined

what is the problem here?

Comment: When your code runs, and it gets to the point `if testVar == "test":`, what do you think should be the result of that comparison? Why? What do you think should be the existing value of `testVar`? Why? How do you expect that value to be set?

Comment: Its just a test

Comment: Hi Wyb253, I recommand [mcve]

Comment: Problem is solved

Comment: Also there is lot of codes and i cant minimalize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `global testVar` is not at all executed as per your code snippet. You need to either declare the global variable outside `testFunc()` or call it before calling `anotherFunc()`

In case of your code, below is the right solution as `testVar` is not just initialized but also assigned value inside `testFunc()`

```
def testFunc():
    global testVar

    if True:
        testVar = input("input something: ")

def anotherFunc():
    if testVar == "test":
        print("okay")

testFunc()
anotherFunc()
```